# How to solve this glitch in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am facing some problems while writing code in VS Code. Whenever I write an inline CSS code in the:

```
<p> </p>
```

tag, specially the style tag, my IDE (VS Code) is not able to autocomplete it. It only happens when I try to use inline CSS in HTML. In case of external CSS it works properly and autocomplete works without any problem:

[image: Checkout this image]

Please help me.

Comment: Try using some VS code extensions for CSS. Try using ctrl + space to trigger auto completion.

Comment: What is the file extension you are using? As standard VSCode will have intellisense if you are editing say a .htm or .html file.